# Internal Server Error after using RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

when I tried to make the URL to be SEO friendly it's getting an error.

this is my whole htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

RewriteRule ^server/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ server?id=$1
RewriteRule ^server/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)/ server?id=$1

ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 500 /500
```

I've seek for the same problem but no one work.

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file reveal what the cause of that error is?

Comment: It's okay now I fix it already

Comment: Which does not at all answer my question nor the question you yourself asked... Please be so kind to document your fix so that others can learn from it. Thanks!